# SQL Convert 'mm/dd/yy' string to date format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, syntax, mariadb

I have table named templog and I have a date column named 'tdate' which stores a string in the 'mm/dd/yy' format. I tried to convert using the following syntax but I receive an error.

```
SELECT convert(datetime,tdate,110) from templog
```

> SQL query: Documentation

SELECT convert(datetime,tdate,110) from templog LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tdate,110) from templog LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: SQL tables/resultsets are by definion **orderless**,  So using ` LIMIT 0, 25` to get the "first" 25 records is pretty much **meaningless** without using `ORDER BY column`.. In fact you ask MySQL here give me 25 records from the table and i don't care which ones i get...if the query was `SELECT convert(datetime,tdate,110) from templog ORDER BY column LIMIT 0, 25` then you ask MySQL the correct thing. Sort the records from the table based on the column and give me the first 25 based on the sorting.

Comment: The syntax you used looks like SQL Server's syntax.  That and _many_ other things are different between the vendors.  Whenever you get 1064, go to the MySQL manual to see what the correct syntax is.  In this case, you would have gotten to the `CONVERT()` function and realize that it does not convert dates.  Then you would need to rummage around until you found "date functions".

Answer (score 1):

For MariaDB, you want `str_to_date()`:

```
SELECT str_to_date(tdate, '%m/%d/%y')
FROM templog
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you